# Node JS backend returning status code 304 on first request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, http-status-code-304

I have a node JS backend and it is returning status code 304 when answering the first request I make to that backend each time I restart my application.
I have read about status code 304 and supposedly it means that the content that the request is  fetching hasn't changed, but, since I get 304 on the first request my front end does not really have any useful data to deal with precisely because it is the first request ever made since the app started.
I have tried to disable the e-tag and stuff like that but in reality nothing helps because I can't get any data on the first request.

Node JS code below:

```
router.get('/results', async function(req,res){
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    const results = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        results.push({evaluation: i, total: 0, equipamentos: []});
    }

    if(authHeader){
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
        await jwt.verify(token, accessTokenSecret, async (err, user) =>{
            if(err){
                return res.sendStatus(403)
            }
            const db_form = client.db("mavideobo").collection("form");
            await db_form.find( {owner: jwt.decode(token).username}).toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    result.forEach(formAnswer => {
                        results[formAnswer.Evaluation - 1].total++;
                    })
                }
            })
            res.status(200).json(results);
        })
    }else{
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
})
```

React function below:

```
const getResultsData = async () => {
        setData([]);
        await fetch("/api/form/results", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
                "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                "Accept": 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => {response.json() 
            console.log(response)})
            .then(res => {
                let listResults = [];
                for (let i in res) {
                    listResults.push(res[i]["total"])
                }
                setData(listResults);
            }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: updated the actual question with some code. thanks

Comment: I think you need to return your response.json()

Comment: On the second piece of code?

Comment: aye. es6 notation gives you two options. `variable => variable.somekey` will naturally return variable.somekey. Your arrow function is leading into a codeblock so you have to manually specify a return value otherwise in the second .then in the fetch res will likely be undefined

Comment: I see what u are saying but it works normally after the first request so maybe that is not the problem